# Extract CSS code related to a specific component

Tags: html, css, web

Is there a way to extract a component (e.g., button) from an online website without going over the CSS(in case the CSS is complicated)?

Let's say I want to extract this button and **only** the CSS related to the component.
[image])

Could it be converting CSS to inline CSS or something similar?

Comment: right click > inspect the button and apply the applied style using your own custom class to button.

Comment: @Praveen But then I have to check every CSS line to see if it affects the selected element? I'm talking in case the code might be complicated, like element selectors + class selectors + id selectors + nested element or class selectors ...

Comment: I'm not sure about your question but the styles tab in web developer tools shows only the applied css.

Comment: @Praveen you've got my points right, but take a look at this gif it takes much more than applied CSS (https://i.imgur.com/wSLrUsJ.gif) you can see it takes all the utils and the unrelated nested selectors.

Comment: just take what is necessary for example in case of button maybe you only need text color background-color border and hover states/transitions.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to get the [window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) of an element, but it would be cluttered with a lot of properties and values that are probably irrelevant to you, and would still miss some important information about where some values came from (for example, if they are calculated by percents or are inherited).

The "computed" tab of the browser's DevTools would give you more clear and detailed information about the values of most properties, but you would still need some manual work. I don't think there is an equivalent JavaScript API that you can use to automate the process, and even if there was, it seems that there isn't a simple criteria to distinguish between the properties and values that are "relevant" and those who are not.